# create file that can be mounted

Tags: startup, filesystem, disk-image

I am trying to create a bootable filesystem `filename.fs` from a directory that contains all the OS files.

My problem is that I cannot create a file that contains a filesystem. I found a [explanation for doing this on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85977/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-mount-it-as-a-filesystem) but macos does not have `mkfs` and `newfs_*` gives me the following error.

```
> newfs_msdos ./clonezilla-live-2.6.6-15-amd64.fs
newfs_msdos: warning: ./clonezilla-live-2.6.6-15-amd64.fs is not a character device
newfs_msdos: ./clonezilla-live-2.6.6-15-amd64.fs: Cannot get partition offset: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I may be going about this all wrong but I have not found any instructions on creating a bootable filesystem from a directory that contains all the files for my OS.

Comment: Creating a filesystem in a disk image and creating a *bootable* filesystem are two different things. The AskUbuntu answer only covers the first part.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to accomplish here (what do you want to do with the  image after you copied Clonezilla onto it)?

Comment: I was looking at how openbsd distributes [index.fs](https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.7/amd64/) disk image and wanted to know how to create such a file with some modification to the source files of clonezilla. Then with the file I would like to archive it and make a bootable usb.

Answer (score 2):

To create a mountable disk image, use `hdiutil`. The straightforward way just creates a DMG which can then be mounted and written to

```
hdiutil create -size 500m -volname CLONEZIL -fs FAT32 clonezilla.dmg
```

To create a DMG with the content of an existing directory use

```
hdiutil create -srcfolder my-clonezilla-dir -volname CLONEZIL -fs FAT32 clonezilla.dmg
```

To mount it afterwards either double-click the DMG file in Finder or run one of the following in Terminal

```
open clonezilla.dmg
hdiutil attach clonezilla.dmg
```

To unmount either eject in Finder or run

```
hdiutil detach /Volumes/CLONEZIL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a disk image then use Disk utility.  Perhaps this Apple Support page can help:
https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/create-a-disk-image-dskutl11888/mac

Answer (score -2):

Creating a file containing a file system on macOS is done with the utility `hdiutil`. `hdiutil`, to quote it's `man` page "uses the DiskImages framework to manipulate disk images".

Bootability of volumes in macOS is controlled by the `bless` utility.

A tutorial on using both utilities is outside the scope of an AskDifferent answer but you could start with [this](http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/disk-management-from-the-command-line-part-3), on hdiutil, and the two `man` pages.

When you have a more specific question then ask away :).

Comment: Helping users to solve problems is always in scope :-) For somebody coming from Linux just learning that the word "Disk Image" is relevant here might be a big hurdle. How can they use `hdiutil` to create a disk image formatted as FAT, how can they use `bless` to make it bootable?

Comment: @tony this isn't the answer to my question but was the answer I needed. Is there any material explaining disk images? I am having trouble discerning helpful material and junk tutorials.